# Multiplying n-D and 1-D numpy arrays along common dimension

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have two numpy arrays `x` and `y` with shapes `(m,n,p)` and `m` respectively.

For all indices `i` between `0` and `m-1`, I want to multiply every element in the block `x[i,:,:]` by `y[i]`.

**How can I achieve this in a single line?**

Related question: [How to multiply numpy 1D with N-D array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58455293/how-to-multiply-numpy-1d-with-n-d-array)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to multiply numpy 1D with N-D array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58455293/how-to-multiply-numpy-1d-with-n-d-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
x * y[:, None, None]
```

Comment: Yes indeed I was just testing that. I initially was trying for the case where the dimension of `y` was `p` instead, but I have realized what I need is for `y` to have shape `(m,)` which is actually easier.